# How can one execute C++ code at runtime from a string representing a function?

Tags: c++, runtime, clang, function-pointers

I'm working on a project wherein I need to be able to save a function string to disk, so I am having the user pass a string of characters that is the actual code of the function and saving it to disk. The opposite is necessary as well; loading a string (from file) and executing as a function at runtime within C++. I need to load this function and return a function pointer to be used in my program. I'm looking at Clang right now, but some of it is a little over my head. So basically I have two questions;

1. Can Clang run code extracted from a string (loaded from disk)?
2. Can a compiled Clang function be represented with a function pointer pointing to it?

Any ideas?

Comment: If you really need this functionality, then you better consider using a scripting language.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for something similar to JavaScript or Lisp's eval(). This is *much* easier to do in an interpreted language.

Comment: Clang has a jitter. You might want to look in that direction

Comment: Yes, it can be done (I have done it), but with difficulty, and constraints and hw features not likely available on a desktop.  Allow me to discourage you.

Answer (score 8):

The simple answer to your question is "yes", the slightly more complex answer is "not at all easily".

Doing it with C++ would require that you compile and link your function into a DLL/shared object, load it, then acquire the exported function. In addition, accepting such code from the user would be a terrible security risk

C++ is a very poor choice for such run-time execution, you would be far better off going with a language meant for that use, JavaScript or Python come to mind.

Comment: Of the interpreted languages, Lua also comes to mind, especially because it's specifically designed to be embeddable within a (host) language.

Answer (score 3):

You can't easily do this in a compiled language.

For a compiled program to execute a C++ function that has been dynamically provided at runtime, that function would need to be *compiled* itself. You *could* make your program call the compiler at runtime to generate a callable library (e.g. one that implements an interface or abstract class and is callable via Dependency Injection), but this is complex and is a project in and of itself. This also means that your application must be packaged with the compiler or must only be installed on systems that contain a compatible compiler - somewhat realistic on Linux, not at all so on Windows.

A better solution would be to use an interpreter. JavaScript and Lisp both come with an `eval()` function that does exactly what you want - it takes a string (in the case of JavaScript) or a list (in the case of Lisp) and *executes it as code*.

A third possibility is to find a C++ *interpreter* that has an eval() function. I'm not sure if any exist. You could try to write one yourself.